# IndexOutOfRangeException in MessageSecurityOverHttpElement when creating WCF client from service reference

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, wcf-binding, service-reference

I have a normal WCF service reference created using 'Add Service Reference' in an application used by thousands of people.

An instance of the client is created using `new MyServiceClient()` and it works 99% of the time, but for some users it can fail with an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I have been unable to reproduce, but from my error reports it seems it might only happen when the application is set to start with Windows, so might be some kind of race condition with some underlying Windows service on startup?

```
Exception (-2146233080): 
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. 
at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext() 
at System.Configuration.PropertyInformationCollection..ctor(ConfigurationElement thisElement) 
at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.MessageSecurityOverHttpElement.ApplyConfiguration(MessageSecurityOverHttp security) 
at System.ServiceModel.Configuration.NonDualMessageSecurityOverHttpElement.ApplyConfiguration(NonDualMessageSecurityOverHttp security) 
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupBinding(String bindingSectionName, String configurationName, BindingCollectionElement bindingCollectionElement, Binding defaultBinding) 
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LookupBinding(String bindingSectionName, String configurationName, ContextInformation context)
at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName) 
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration) 
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address) 
at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress) 
at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory() 
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait) 
at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
```

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://xxxxxxxx.com/Services/MyService.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" contract="MyService.IMyService" name="WSHttpBinding_IMyService" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't encounter a similar issue yet. The error indicates that you are trying to access an index in your ArrayList that does not exist in other words out of range.
If the error occurred on the client side, I think it may be that client environment caused this issue. For example, is there a corresponding dotnetframework runtime version installed, system problems? Try to fix these problems then removing and re-adding service references.
Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks but it's not an ArrayList that I constructed, it's constructed by .NET from the config file and it works for 99% of users. For the ones where it fails I have confirmation that it works if they restart their machine (no confirmation yet on whether an app restart is enough).

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, the service is reliable for most users and can be called normally. For this particular user, it may be a problem with the machine/operating system.
I suggest you install Dotnetframework runtime and re-build the client project again(re-add the service reference again)